# picking element game

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

This is a simple game: 
There is a set, A={a1,...,an}, the opponents can choose one of the first or last elements of set, and at the end the one who collect bigger numbers wins. Now say each participants dose his best, what I need to do is write a Dynamic algorithm to estimate their score.
any idea or clue is truly appreciated.

Comment: sorry for poor grammar and stuff

Comment: Is this homework? What constitutes the first or last element of a set (sets have no ordering so this is not clear)? How are the scores calculated? What have you tried so far? Where is it going wrong?

Comment: You could try adapting the algorithm for a very similar game posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571900

Comment: @ChrisWalton Yes, it's not the actual question but a part of it. Set has no order, integers randomly chosen, randomly distributed. The score is calculated using the elements that participants picked, sum of integer that they choose. I'd write this recurrence: _italic_ s(n) = s(n-1)U{an|an=min{aj,ak}}, s(n-1)={ai|ai in A, j<i<k}, s(1)=min{A} _italic_ then f(A) = max{firs(A),last(A)} + f(s(n-2)) would be score of the one starts the game and f(s(n-1)) = max{firs(s(n-1)),last(s(n-1))} + f(s(n-3)) score of the other one. but so far i don't think it's the right way to go.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz wise council, tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### EXAMPLE CODE

Here is Python code to compute the optimal score for first and second players.

```
A=[3,1,1,3,1,1,3]

cache={}
def go(a,b):
    """Find greatest difference between player 1 coins and player 2 coins when choosing from A[a:b]"""
    if a==b: return 0 # no stacks left
    if a==b-1: return A[a] # only one stack left
    key=a,b
    if key in cache:
        return cache[key]

    v=A[a]-go(a+1,b) # taking first stack
    v=max(v,A[b-1]-go(a,b-1)) # taking last stack

    cache[key]=v
    return v

v = go(0,len(A))
n=sum(A)
print (n+v)/2,(n-v)/2
```

### COUNTEREXAMPLE

Note that the code includes a counter example to one of the other answers to this question.

Consider the case [3,1,1,3,1,1,3].

By symmetry, the first players move always leaves the pattern [1,1,3,1,1,3].

For this the sum of even elements is 1+3+1=5, while the sum of odd is 1+1+3=5, so the argument is that from this position the second player will always win 5, and the first player will always win 5, so the first player will win (as he gets 5 in addition to the 3 from the first move).

However, this logic is flawed because the second player can actually get more.

```
First player takes 3, leaves [1,1,3,1,1,3] (only choice by symmetry)
Second player takes 3, leaves [1,1,3,1,1]
First player takes 1, leaves [1,3,1,1] (only choice by symmetry)
Second player takes 1, leaves [1,3,1]
First player takes 1, leaves [3,1] (only choice by symmetry)
Second player takes 3, leaves [1]
First player takes 1
```

So overall first player gets 3+1+1+1=6, while second gets 3+1+3=7 and second player wins.

The flaw is that although it is true that the second player can play such that they will win all even or all odd positions, this is not optimal play and they can actually do better than this in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint: to write a dynamic programming algorithm, you typically need a recurrence. Given

```
A={a1,...,an}
```

The recurrence would look something like this

```
f(A)= max( f({a1,...,a_n-1}) ,  f({a2,...,a_n}) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the recurrence relation given by dfb may not lead to right answer 
as it is not leading to the right sub-optimal structure !
Assume the Player A begins the game :
the structure of problem for him is [a1,a2,...an]
After choosing an element , either a1 or an , its player B's turn to play , and then after that move it is player A's move.
So after two moves , Player A's turn will come again and this will be the right sub-problem for him .The right recurrence relation will be

Suppose from i to j elements are left :

`A(i,j)= max(min( A(i+1,j-1),A(i+2,j)+a[i] ), min(A(i,j-2),A(i+1,j-1))+a[j])`

Refer to the following link :
http://people.csail.mit.edu/bdean/6.046/dp/

Comment: Kindly watch the video on that link,its short and clear , click on optimal strategy for a game topic in the link.

Comment: Really nice! +1 for the link!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you do not need dynamic programming, because it is easy to find an explicit solution for the game above.

Case n is even or n = 1. 
The second player to move will always lose.

Case n odd and n > 1.
The second player has a winning strategy iff one of the following 2 scenarios happen:

1. The elements with even index have bigger sum than all the elements with odd index
2. All odd elements except the last have bigger sum than all the remainings AND
   All odd elements except the first have bigger sum than all the remainings.

Proof sketch:

Case n is even or n = 1: Let Sodd and Seven be the sum of all elements with even/odd indexes. Assume that Sodd > Seven, same argument hold otherwise. The first player has a winning strategy, since he can play in such a way that he will get all odd indexed items.

The case n is odd and n > 1 can also be resolved directly. In fact the first player has two options, he can get the first or last element of the set. Of the remaining elements, partition them the two subsets with odd and even indexes; by the argument above, the second player is going to take the subset with largest sum. If you expand the tree game you will end up with the statement above.